# How to use App password like Office outlook desktop uses in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Can anyone help me figure out how you can get an access token using [app password](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-app-password-for-Office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183) in the same outlook does it on the desktop app.

I know there is a password flow but [that](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-app-password-for-Office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183)  one just requires regular user passwords. I am unable to find any info on how to use app passwords.

From what I can tell app passwords can skip two factor auth and I want to be able to do that to run automated tests?

Are there any samples of this or am I missing something why you can't make something like this?

Comment: Here are some further information about app passwords with multi factor authentication: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords)